# Como fazer uma barra de rolagem

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo um grupo de cartões, e quando a tela é grande eles ficam normais, mas quando eu diminuo eles ficam pequenos. Queria criar uma barra de rolagem para que quando fosse em telas menores, o tamanho dos cards ficassem o mesmo, porém com a barra de rolagem. Eu tentei utilizando o `overflow-x` para tentar ficar responsiva, porém não obtive sucesso. No caso eu quero uma barra de rolagem horizontal.

Meu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Exemplo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
  .conteudo{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .card{
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
      width: 250px;
      margin: 10px;
      height: 200px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
</style>
</head>
 <body>
<div style="overflow-x: auto">
  <div class="conteudo">
    <div class="card">1</div>
    <div class="card">2</div>
    <div class="card">3</div>
    <div class="card">4</div>
    <div class="card">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você deseja uma barra de rolagem **horizontal** (e não **vertical** como você afirma no fim da sua pergunta), seu código está certinho, **apenas** o que você precisa fazer para que os cards tenham sempre a mesma largura, é trocar a propriedade  `width: 250px;` por  `min-width: 250px;`.

A propriedade `min-width`, dentro de um flexbox, *trava* a largura do elemento no valor especificado (`250px`), criando, assim, o scroll horizontal caso você diminua a tela a uma largura menor:

```css
.conteudo{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   width: 100%;
}
.card{
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   min-width: 250px;
   margin: 10px;
   height: 200px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-x: auto">
  <div class="conteudo">
    <div class="card">1</div>
    <div class="card">2</div>
    <div class="card">3</div>
    <div class="card">4</div>
    <div class="card">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Vc colocou o `overflow-X` no elemento errado, vc colocou em uma `div` de fora, tinha que ser na `div` de dentro a `div .conteudo`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além disso, como vc está usando `flex` vc tem que definir um `min-width` para o `card` e não um  `width` simples.

Outro coisa que vc precisa fazer para o scroll horizontal funcionar como o esperado é só adicionar o `justify-content: center;` só quando a tela for maior que 1330px!

Segue o código da imagem acima.

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.conteudo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* justify-content: center; */
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.card {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width:1330px) {
    .conteudo {
        justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="conteudo">
        <div class="card">1</div>
        <div class="card">2</div>
        <div class="card">3</div>
        <div class="card">4</div>
        <div class="card">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No caso você precisa especificar um tamanho máximo para a barra ser criada:

```
.conteudo{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 80px; 
  }
```

Na ultima linha defini a altura máxima como 80px, e automaticamente foi criado a scrollbar vertical.

Comment: Cara eu queria barra horizontal, mas vlw, sabe como conseguir colocar horizontal